# Outputting to file with comma causing new line in file in ruby

Tags: ruby

So I have a file that I am trying to write to after getting a username, password and role from the user to add to this file. Everything appears to work well, but when I open the file for writing and enter the puts command, it creates a new line after the password section. Here is a snippet of the code.

```
File.open("user.file", "a") do |file|
  file.puts "#{userName}=#{passwordEncoded},#{role},enabled"
```

And here is what I get in the file itself afterwards

```
danny=ieSV55Qc+eQOaYDRSha/AjzNTJE=
,ROLE,enabled
```

It might have something to do with the = at the end of the encoded password but I am not sure. The passwords always end in an equal size so maybe that causes issues? But I am not sure here.

Comment: `passwordEncoded` contains a newline char?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `chomp` call to `passwordEncoded` variable to remove newline:

```
File.open("user.file", "a") do |file|
  file.puts "#{userName}=#{passwordEncoded.chomp},#{role},enabled"
```

Answer (score 4):

Your `passwordEncoded` variable ends in a newline. The actual contents of the variable will be

```
"ieSV55Qc+eQOaYDRSha/AjzNTJE=\n"
```

There is no problem with your code. It is behaving exactly as expected.